# Intel Desktop Board DZ77GA-70K WLAN Installation Issue

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, motherboard

I have just built a machine using an Intel DZ77GA-70K motherboard. It comes with a Bluetooth/WLAN module that connects to a USB header on the motherboard.

I have been unable to install the drivers for the WLAN device. The Bluethooth device is working fine. I suspect it is a hardware issue and that I would need to return the motherboard but would like to put it out there to see if I have missed something.

Can someone advise whether I need to return this motherboard for a swap or whether this is an installation problem? I am leaning towards it being a hardware problem.

Here's a screenshot of the Device Manager displaying the problematic device.

[image: Screenshot of the Device Manager displaying the problematic device]

I have found the following error report in Windows Event Viewer when Windows tries to install the WLAN device.

```
Fault bucket 388098504, type 5
Event Name: PnPDeviceProblemCode
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: x86
P2: USB\UNKNOWN
P3: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
P4: 0000002B
P5: unknown
P6: unknown
P7: unknown
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\Umar Farooq Khawaja\AppData\Local\Temp\DMI583D.tmp.log.xml
C:\Windows\inf\usb.inf

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Umar Farooq Khawaja\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_x86_a796cc5babf24d790d38cfc7dd844dad2e847e4_05f8645d

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: fa64afec-2b29-11e2-b2ae-94dbc995e988
Report Status: 0
```

The report contained the following contents:

```
Version=1
EventType=PnPDeviceProblemCode
EventTime=129970206079092332
Consent=1
UploadTime=129970206079248333
ReportIdentifier=fa64afec-2b29-11e2-b2ae-94dbc995e988
Response.BucketId=388098504
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Architecture
Sig[0].Value=x86
Sig[1].Name=Hardware Id
Sig[1].Value=USB\UNKNOWN
Sig[2].Name=Setup class GUID
Sig[2].Value={36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
Sig[3].Name=PnP problem code
Sig[3].Value=0000002B
Sig[4].Name=Driver name
Sig[4].Value=unknown
Sig[5].Name=Driver version
Sig[5].Value=unknown
Sig[6].Name=Driver date
Sig[6].Value=unknown
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.1.0.256.1
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=2057
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Could not load driver software
ConsentKey=PnPDeviceProblemCode
AppName=Unknown Device
AppPath=C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
ReportDescription=Windows was able to successfully install device driver software, but the driver software encountered a problem when it tried to run. The problem code is 43.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have decided that the motherboard is faulty and to return the motherboard. I have also replaced it with an Asus P8Z77-V Pro, which I think might be a better board than the Intel.